# Create React App serviceworker is not including one of the generated files

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, service-worker

TLDR: It seems that one of the chunk js files generated by Create React App is not being included in the serviceworker.

We have what I believe is a pretty vanilla Create React App (version 4.0.3) configuration with the serviceworker turned on. When I do a build ( with npm run build), it creates a build/static/js folder with two chunk files: a main chunk file (i.e. main.9c46d9a1.chunk.js) and a 2.* chunk js file (i.e. 2.ab51bb70.chunk.js). In the asset-manifest.json file that gets generated they are listed like this:

- "main.js": "./static/js/main.9c46d9a1.chunk.js",
- "static/js/2.ab51bb70.chunk.js": "./static/js/2.ab51bb70.chunk.js",

I've added logging in service-worker.ts to spin through self.__WB_MANIFEST and print out the URL's from all of the PrecacheEntry objects. When I load the app in the browser, the serviceWorker gets loaded, and it prints this:

```
WB_MANIFEST[0]: [object Object], ./index.html service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[1]: [object Object], ./static/css/2.c01127d3.chunk.css service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[2]: [object Object], ./static/css/main.f8831819.chunk.css service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[3]: [object Object], ./static/js/main.9c46d9a1.chunk.js service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[4]: [object Object], ./static/js/runtime-main.fbeb3cf7.js service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[5]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-brands-400.5a306647.svg service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[6]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-brands-400.64ed668a.woff2 service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[7]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-brands-400.a37daad3.woff service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[8]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-brands-400.ccef0bae.eot service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[9]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-brands-400.cd5546e6.ttf service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[10]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-duotone-900.0c96b470.svg service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[11]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-duotone-900.2314c0f5.woff2 service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[12]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-duotone-900.3fdb2223.eot service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[13]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-duotone-900.a0e65102.ttf service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[14]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-duotone-900.c94100ae.woff service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[15]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-light-300.006ea550.svg service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[16]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-light-300.1f49a99d.woff2 service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[17]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-light-300.6373bfef.ttf service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[18]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-light-300.c08a2df1.eot service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[19]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-light-300.e5757ebc.woff service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[20]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-regular-400.27f55d89.woff service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[21]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-regular-400.3a392f72.woff2 service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[22]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-regular-400.51f647b6.svg service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[23]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-regular-400.7088e010.ttf service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[24]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-regular-400.916bee0f.eot service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[25]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-solid-900.33d63de0.eot service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[26]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-solid-900.471ea344.woff2 service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[27]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-solid-900.b82704a9.svg service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[28]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-solid-900.c6787dfa.woff service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[29]: [object Object], ./static/media/fa-solid-900.d0c4cb0e.ttf service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[30]: [object Object], ./static/media/stateface-regular-webfont.338df6ef.ttf service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[31]: [object Object], ./static/media/stateface-regular-webfont.8242df53.eot service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[32]: [object Object], ./static/media/stateface-regular-webfont.ceeb3940.woff service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[33]: [object Object], ./static/media/stateface-regular-webfont.fe14ecab.svg service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[34]: [object Object], ./static/media/wb-btn.dd321b43.woff2 service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[35]: [object Object], ./static/media/wb-btn.e81ff3cf.woff service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[36]: [object Object], ./static/media/wb.3b7c6f3d.woff service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[37]: [object Object], ./static/media/wb.92fe6c4c.ttf service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[38]: [object Object], ./static/media/wb.e244f767.svg service-worker.js:1:54224
WB_MANIFEST[39]: [object Object], ./static/media/wb.ec198838.eot service-worker.js:1:54224
```

Note that it does not include the 2.* chunk js file. What this causes to happen is:

- When version A of the app is installed and the serviceworker for it is loaded in the browser, the serviceworker loads all of its files, and the 2.* chunk js file gets cached. If I open the browser development tools, go to the network tab, and reload the browser I see that the main chunk js file is being loaded from serviceworker, and the 2.* chunk js file is being loaded from cache.

[image: main chunk from serviceworker]

[image: 2.* chunk from cache]

- Then either the browser cache (but not serviceworker) gets cleared or expires, and the browser gets closed.
- Sometime later a new version B of the app gets installed, so that the files from version A are no longer on the server.
- Sometime after that the app is opened in the browser. The old version of the serviceworker (from version A of the app) gets loaded, and goes to look for the old version 2.* chunk file. It can't find it (because it wasn't in the serviceworker, and isn't on the server anymore, and the browser cache has cleared/expired). The app doesn't load but instead gets a blank white screen. The serviceworker does see that a new version is available and registers it as the "next" serviceworker, but you have to close the app and reopen it to get rid of the blank white screen and see that next version of the app.

I can force the 2.* chunk js file to be stored in the serviceworker by modifying service-worker.ts and adding a registerRoute call that looks for this file and adds it. But my understanding is this file, since it's auto-generated by the create react app build, should be getting added automatically in the call to `precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);` in service-worker.ts.

I suspect that the differences in the paths here, from asset-manifest.json file, may somehow be related to the 2.* chunk js file to not be loaded, but that's just a guess.

- "main.js": "./static/js/main.9c46d9a1.chunk.js",
- "static/js/2.ab51bb70.chunk.js": "./static/js/2.ab51bb70.chunk.js",

There is also a similar entry in asset-manifest.json for a 2.* chunk css file, and that is getting added to WB_MANIFEST (see the logs above), so my suspicion may not have merit.

- "static/css/2.c01127d3.chunk.css": "./static/css/2.c01127d3.chunk.css",

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes` configuration option might be at play here. In `c-r-a`, it's [set to 5mb](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/10048), so if your chunk is larger than 5mb, it will be excluded from the list of assets to precache.

There *should* be a warning message logged as part of your `webpack` build process if that's happening, explaining what the current limit is and which assets exceed that limit.

Finding a way to decrease the size of the chunk is the best approach, and huge chunks aren't a great user experience to begin with. But if you can't reduce the chunk size, then ejecting and modifying the `maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes` configuration in the `InjectManifest` `webpack` plugin configuration is your other option.

Comment: Jeff, that appears to be exactly our issue. I found the warning in the build log, and the 2.* chunk file is > 5 mb. We'll look into breaking it up. Thanks for your help!